# Is it possible to perform Includes with flask?

Tags: html, templates, flask, jinja2, ssi

Say I have a template layout saved in template.html.  This template includes a banner, side navigation, content container, and footer. Can I use flask to break up these page elements in such a way that I can have files such as banner.html, sidenavigation.html, etc. and render these different files within template.html?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

From: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#include

template.html

```html
{% include 'banner.html' %}
{% include 'sidenavigation.html' %}
{% include 'content.html' %}
{% include 'footer.html' %}
```

Comment: You might also want to look at Template Inheritance, as it might be a more powerful way of doing what you want: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#template-inheritance

Comment: It should be noted that you can not create an inheritance hierarchy in Jinja2, you can only inherit a document one level deep.

Comment: @MadPumpkin: What exactly do you mean my that? You can extend as many levels deep as you want. It's not possible to extend a single template from multiple others (perhaps that is what you meant?)

Answer (score 2):

By default, Flask uses Jinja2 as its template engine. See Jinja's [Template Designer Documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/) how it's done.

Comment: But is it possible to highlight, which page is active in sidenavigation.html?

Comment: @jOSe You can make use of the `scoped` keyword in the `block` definition within "sidenavigation.html".  See Jinja's ["Block Nesting and Scope" section](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#block-nesting-and-scope).  Their example is `{% block loop_item scoped %}{{ item }}{% endblock %}` which allows `item` to pull its definition from the inheriting template.

Answer (score 1):

Before you start, you need to write these components separately to other html files as pure html. For example, these files shouldn't contain any jinja syntax. After that, according to the [documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#include), you can easily import them into your template.html file by calling `{% include 'filename.html' %}` code.

Answer (score 0):

Think carefully about whether to use inheritance (extends) vs composition (include).

If you have several pages with nearly identical structure, inheritance may be the best choice.  But if you are 'planning for change', composition may be more flexible, and only slightly longer.

It's common for folks new to object-orientation to overuse inheritance.  See "Uncle Bob" on the question, at https://twitter.com/unclebobmartin/status/1308029538463625219?lang=en