# Flask return content to html page

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm working on a page (index.html) where visitors can enter some text and submit a message. This message is written to a file (messages.html).
On the same page (index.html) I want to show the content of messages.html.

Most of this works already. Problem is, I can't find a way to wrap the messages in html, so the browser shows the content properly.

Any suggestions?

This is my python file (index.py):

```
from flask import Flask, request, url_for, redirect, render_template
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import TextAreaField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
from flask import Response

import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')


class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    name = TextAreaField('name', validators=[DataRequired()])

@app.route('/')
def index():
    form = MyForm()
    with app.open_resource('messages.html') as g:
        content = g.read()
    return render_template('index.html',
                            content = content,
                            form = form)

@app.route('/p1')
def p1():
    return render_template('p1.html')

@app.route('/p2')
def p2():
    return render_template('p2.html')

@app.route('/entry', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def submitmsg():
    if request.method=='POST':
        t = datetime.datetime.now()
        strT = t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        with open("messages.html","a") as f:
            f.write("Bericht op: " + strT + "<br>")
            f.write(request.form["name"] + "<br>") 
            f.write("============================================================================<br>")
        f.close()
        form = MyForm()
        with app.open_resource('messages.html') as g:
            content = g.read()
        return render_template('index.html',
                                content = content,
                                form = form)

if __name__ == "__main__":
 app.run(host='0.0.0.0',debug=True)
```

And here's the template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="1">
    <tr align="center">
        <td>
            <a href="{{ url_for('p1') }}">Foto's</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <h1>berichten</h1>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{ url_for('p2') }}">Webcam</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table width="100%" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td width="50%"><h1>berichten lezen</h1></td>
        <td align="right"><h1>bericht schrijven</h1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="50%">{{ content }}</td>
        <td align="right">
            <form action="/entry" method="POST">
                Schrijf hier je bericht:<br>
                {{ form.name(rows='20',cols='60') }}
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Bericht versturen">
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to perform Includes with flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679038/is-it-possible-to-perform-includes-with-flask)

Comment: What output do you want? And what have you tried? Have you looked into conditional formatting w/ jinja?